# Oracle: select max date per month per year from table

Tags: database, oracle11g

I have a table with a set of business dates I need to select the max date per month and year tried using the last_day function but that returns the last day not the max date of that month.please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MAX` is an aggregate function, so you need to figure out how to group all of the days of the month together. The easiest way to do that is apply a function that will return the same value for every day in that month. `LAST_DAY` would work, but I prefer `TRUNC` (with `'MM'` specified).

```
SELECT MAX(your_column) FROM your_table GROUP BY TRUNC(your_column, 'MM')
```